# Azure SuggestAsync map to POCO

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

i am using Azure search sdk 3.0.1
with syntax similar to below, where T is the POCO object , and i want List returned

```
   await indexClient.Documents.SuggestAsync<T>(input.Term, suggesterName,
                       indexType.GetAutoCompleteSearchParameters())
```

this gives me back DocumentSuggestResults, i did not see any examples or methods in azure sdk that will directly give me Ienumerable or convert this DocumentSuggestResults to Ienumerable . Is there a easy way to do this? or i need unpack this object myself loop and create a Ienumerable myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentSuggestResults` does not implement `IEnumerable`, but you can always just access the `Results` property and use LINQ to get at the documents:

```
IEnumerable<SuggestResult<T>> results =
    (await indexClient.Documents.SuggestAsync<T>(input.Term, suggesterName,
                   indexType.GetAutoCompleteSearchParameters())).Results;
IEnumerable<T> documents = results.Select(r => r.Document);
```

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.SuggestResult<T>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: .Results has SuggestResult<T>

Comment: That's what I get for compiling in my head. :-)  I'll fix the answer.